# using get-odbcdsn across all domain computers

Tags: powershell, object

So I need to create a report of what odbc-dsns are on computers.

The first hurdle I'm trying to do is get the csv to output correctly on MINE. Then I figure I'll just deploy a runonce group policy with the script set to append.

The problem is that get-odbcdns returns an object. That object has:

Name: the friendly name of the odbc
Attribute : {Description}

I just want to be able to formatlist with the VALUE of the {Description} value inside the Attribute property.  I can't figure out how to do that.

Whenever I go | fl name, attribute

it returns 1sl-den-db01 and {description} I would like for it to actually parse out description from Attribute. No idea how. Thoughts?

Comment: Get-ODBCDSNs | Select Name, @{n='Description';e={$_.Attribute.Description}}

Comment: Holyshit. Why is that so complicated?!

Comment: Because you're selecting from a secondary attribute/object and want to have a nice name. As a note there might be cases were Description isn't available for a specific object. In turn you might get empty lines with just a name and no description.